# Sum number values from multiple dimensions when 3 other dimensions have a text value

Tags: count, case, looker-studio

I have a data source spreadsheet that has text types in 3 dimensions. I am wanting to look up a text value and return the number value that is in another dimension. So example would be in the following spreadsheet. "24in Monitor" is the text value found in peripherals1, peripherals2, and peripherals3 dimensions. I want to return the sum of the P1 Quantity, P2 Quantity and P3 Quantity anytime that this text value is found in the peripherals1, peripherals2 and peripherals3 dimensions.

[Data_Source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O9bd_rVLqeVLOqoPxNS-esZQ7WkjMyyWGceCw2fXwPw/edit?usp=sharing)

Tried to use a Case function that converted the text value to a number based on the text.

```
CASE
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("24in Monitor") Then 1
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("24in Monitor") Then 1
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("24in Monitor") Then 1
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("32in 4K Monitor") Then 2
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("32in 4K Monitor") Then 2
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("32in 4K Monitor") Then 2
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Standard USB-C Docking Station") Then 3
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Standard USB-C Docking Station") Then 3
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Standard USB-C Docking Station") Then 3
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Performance USB-C Docking Station") Then 4
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Performance USB-C Docking Station") Then 4
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Performance USB-C Docking Station") Then 4
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Macbook Docking Station") Then 5
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Macbook Docking Station") Then 5
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Macbook Docking Station") Then 5
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Chromebook USB-C Docking Station") Then 6
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Chromebook USB-C Docking Station") Then 6
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Chromebook USB-C Docking Station") Then 6
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Headset, USB-A") Then 7
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Headset, USB-A") Then 7
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Headset, USB-A") Then 7
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Headset, USB-C") Then 8
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Headset, USB-C") Then 8
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Headset, USB-C") Then 8
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Standard USB Wired Keyboard") Then 9
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Standard USB Wired Keyboard") Then 9
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Standard USB Wired Keyboard") Then 9
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Standard USB Wired Mouse") Then 10
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Standard USB Wired Mouse") Then 10
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Standard USB Wired Mouse") Then 10
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Standard USB Wired Keyboard/Mouse Combo") Then 11
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Standard USB Wired Keyboard/Mouse Combo") Then 11
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Standard USB Wired Keyboard/Mouse Combo") Then 11
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Standard MacOS US Wired Keyboard") Then 12
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Standard MacOS US Wired Keyboard") Then 12
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Standard MacOS US Wired Keyboard") Then 12
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Premium Wireless Apple Keyboard") Then 13
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Premium Wireless Apple Keyboard") Then 13
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Premium Wireless Apple Keyboard") Then 13
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Premium Wireless Apple Mouse") Then 14
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Premium Wireless Apple Mouse") Then 14
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Premium Wireless Apple Mouse") Then 14
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Premium Wireless Windows Mouse") Then 15
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Premium Wireless Windows Mouse") Then 15
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Premium Wireless Windows Mouse") Then 15
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Premium Wireless Keyboard/Mouse Combo") Then 16
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Premium Wireless Keyboard/Mouse Combo") Then 16
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Premium Wireless Keyboard/Mouse Combo") Then 16
    WHEN Peripherals1 IN ("Logitech Webcam") Then 17
    WHEN Peripherals2 IN ("Logitech Webcam") Then 17
    WHEN Peripherals3 IN ("Logitech Webcam") Then 17 
  END
```

And then used another case function that attempted to count

```
CASE
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 1 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 2 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 3 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 4 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 5 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 6 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 7 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 8 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 9 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 10 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 11 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 12 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 13 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 14 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 15 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 16 Then gpt_test
    WHEN Peripherals_Convert = 17 Then gpt_test
    ELSE NULL
  END
```

The gpt_test function was a coalesce as follows:

```
COALESCE(P1 Quantity, 0) + COALESCE(P2 Quantity, 0) + COALESCE(P3 Quantity, 0)
```

I then used a filter on a scorecard that included only when the peripherals1, peripherals2, and peripherals3 contained the text "value here" from the list and only if the Incoming/Outgoing dimension had "Outgoing".

[Scorecard Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhMcP.png)

Issue I am having is that the count is incorrect based on a manual count within the spreadsheet. The count should be about 450 but i seem to get 586 and dont understand how. I would expect the value to be 450 not 586.

Looking for a solution to this as I need to create a total of 36 scorecards that will be for the columns "peripheralsX" and "Miscellaneous ItemsX" in the spreadsheet.